# Working sample for jclouds working with amazon ec2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jclouds

I am implementing tool creating servers via amazon ec2, we tried to use jclouds project (were succeed working with Rackspace Cloud) https://github.com/jclouds

I found a sample https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-examples/tree/master/ec2-windows, but it doesn't work (really, jclouds updated version up to 2.0.2 for 4 years). I need to get working sample or actual documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [compute-basics](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-examples/tree/master/compute-basics) example is kept more up to date. Could you give it a try?

Comment: I need Amazon ec2 provider

Comment: That code is generic, works for any provider supported by jclouds. Take a look at the readme to see how to run it for aws.